# checking the same condition for all elements in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to code a basic hangman game. When the user guesses correctly the word then the word is uploaded to an "answer" array and displayed to the user , when the guessed word is wrong then a warning should say "try again" and the input value cleared.

The thing is even when one word is actually guessed correctly there's still all the other words that were not so I end up getting the same warning "try again"

So I think I need to loop the original word and check to see if none of the elements are equal to the letter guess and for that I'm using every() but I can't make it work and "try again" always shows...

Help please

````
        function generate(){
            pickedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];   
            console.log(pickedWord)
            for(let i = 0; i<pickedWord.length; i++){           
                word[i] = "_";
            } 
            wordGuess.textContent = word.join(" ");
        }

        function getInput(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let guess = input.value.toLowerCase();  
            if(guess.length > 1){
                alert("type just one letter")
                input.value = ""        
            }

            else{   

                for(let i=0; i < pickedWord.length; i++){
                     if(guess === pickedWord[i]){
                        word[i] = guess;
                        wordGuess.textContent = word.join(" ");
                        input.value="";                                      
                    }

                     else { 
                        const letter = [pickedWord[i]]
                        console.log(letter)
                        const itemGuessed = letter.every(el => el !== guess)

                            if(itemGuessed){

                            alerta.textContent = "try again"
                            input.value="";
                        }
                    }   

                 }

            }

        }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You actually didn't specify what does the `words` array look like, so I'm gonna assume tht it's an array of strings. Something like

`const words = ['applejuice', 'bananashake', 'peanutbutter'];`

---

So first of all, I actually don't understand what is the purpose of `const letter = [pickedWord[i]]`. Say the picked word was `'apple'`, and `i` was 0, then `letter` will be equal to `['a']`, which makes the line `const itemGuessed = letter.every(el => el !== guess)` completely meaningless.

I also think it's better to check if `guess` is included in the `pickedWord` outside of the loop, using either `pickedWord.every(el => el !== guess)` or `pickedWord.includes(guess)` (though I prefer the latter!).

Anyway, I had a little rewrite on your code:

```js
let pickedWord;
const words = ['applejuice', 'bananashake', 'peanutbutter'];
let word = [];

function generate() {
    pickedWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    word = Array(pickedWord.length).fill('_');
    console.log(pickedWord, word.join(''));
}

let guessedLetters = [];

function getInput(input){
    // e.preventDefault();
    const guess = input.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');  
    if(guess.length !== 1){
        alert("type one letter");
    }else{
        if (pickedWord.includes(guess) === -1) {
            alert("letter not in word");
        }else if(guessedLetters.includes(guess)) {
            alert("that letter is already guessed");
        }else{
            guessedLetters.push(guess)
            for (let i = 0; i < pickedWord.length; i++) {
                if(guess === pickedWord[i]){
                    word[i] = guess;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

generate();

//cases where 1: same letter guessed twice
//            2: more than 1 letters guessed at once
//            3: capital letters guessed
//            4: empty string / space guessed
for (let input of ['', '   ', 'a', 'a', 'B', 'c', 'Cc', 'd', 'E', 'f', 'g', 'h']){
  getInput(input);
  console.log(word.join(''));
}
```

Note that I removed `input.value="";` line for the demonstration purposes.
Please feel free to ask anything if you had a problem with my code. cheers!